# multiple buffers using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, system-calls, thread-synchronization

I need some algorithm help with a multithreaded program I'm writing. It's basically the cp command in unix, but with a read thread and a write thread. I'm using semaphores for thread synchronization. I have structs for buffer and thread data defined as

```
struct bufType {
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int numBytes;
};

struct threadData {
    int fd;
    bufType buf;
};
```

and a global array of bufType. Code for my main is

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int in, out;
    pthread_t Producer, Consumer;
    threadData producerData, consumerData;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "Error: incorrect number of params" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if ((in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0666)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Error: cannot open input file" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if ((out = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Cannot create output file" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    sem_init(&sem_empty, 0, NUM_BUFFERS);
    sem_init(&sem_full, 0, 0);

    pthread_create (&Producer, NULL, read_thread, (void *) &producerData);
    pthread_create (&Consumer, NULL, write_thread, (void *) &consumerData);

    pthread_join(Producer, NULL);
    pthread_join(Consumer, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

and read and write threads:

```
void *read_thread(void *data)
{
    threadData *thread_data;
    thread_data = (threadData *) data;

    while((thread_data->buf.numBytes = slow_read(thread_data->fd, thread_data->buf.buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0)
    {
        sem_post(&sem_full);
        sem_wait(&sem_empty);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *write_thread(void *data)
{
    threadData *thread_data;
    thread_data = (threadData *) data;

    sem_wait(&sem_full);
    slow_write(thread_data->fd, thread_data->buf.buf, thread_data->buf.numBytes);
    sem_post(&sem_empty);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

So my issue is in what to assign to my threadData variables in main, and my semaphore logic in the read and write threads. I appreciate any help you're able to give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a windows guy who does not use file descriptors I might be wrong  with the in's and out's but I think this needs to be done in your main in order to setup the threadData structures.

```
producerData.fd = in;
consumerData.fd = out;
```

Then declare ONE SINGLE object of type bufType for both structures. Change for example the definition of threadData to

```
struct threadData {
    int fd;
    bufType* buf;
};
```

and in your Main, you write

```
bufType buffer;
producerData.buf = &buffer;
consumerData.buf = &buffer;
```

Then both threads will use a common buffer. Otherwise you would be writing to the producerData buffer, but the consumerData buffer will stay empty (and this is where your writer thread is looking for data)

Then you need to change your signalling logic. Right now your program cannot accept input that exceeds `BUFFER_SIZE`, because your write thread will only write once. There needs to be a loop around it. And then you need some mechanism that signals the writer thread that no more data will be sent. For example you could do this

```
void *read_thread(void *data)
{
    threadData *thread_data;
    thread_data = (threadData *) data;

    while((thread_data->buf->numBytes = slow_read(thread_data->fd, thread_data->buf->buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        sem_post(&sem_full);
        sem_wait(&sem_empty);
    }
    sem_post(&sem_full); // Note that thread_data->buf->numBytes <= 0 now

    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *write_thread(void *data)
{
    threadData *thread_data;
    thread_data = (threadData *) data;


    sem_wait(&sem_full);
    while (thread_data->buf->numBytes > 0)
    {
        slow_write(thread_data->fd, thread_data->buf->buf, thread_data->buf->numBytes);
        sem_post(&sem_empty);
        sem_wait(&sem_full);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Hope there are no more errors, did not test solution. But the concept should be what you were asking for.

Comment: I think this will put me on the right track. Only problem, I'm required to use multiple buffers and I forgot to include that in the question. Thus, the array of bufType

Comment: I dont understand the way this should work with multiple buffers. Both threads have to share the buffer or they cannot communicate

Comment: Or do you mean that there are two buffers, one of which gets written while the other one is read, and then they get swapped?

Comment: basically we're trying to emulate the dining philosophers problem; we have a pool of shared resources. read gets the first available empty buffer and "produces" and write gets the first full buffer and "consumes" it. And the process is synchronized with semaphores

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as assigning the thread data with an array index in a loop in main? I haven't tried that yet because I haven't gotten it working with a single buffer

Comment: I think it is not so easy. That problem is significantly more complex than a simple producer-consumer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common buffer pool, either a circular array or a linked lists. Here is a link to a zip of a Windows example that is similar to what you're asking, using linked lists as part of a inter-thread messaging system to buffer data. Other than the creation of the mutexes, semaphores, and the write thread, the functions are small and simple. [mtcopy.zip](http://rcgldr.net/misc/mtcopy.zip) .